# How to divide y-axis (to change units) AND change format (no decimals)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a DataFrame with a different unit than the one of my dataset (without changing the df or copying).

So I divide by 1000 following the advice [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575257/how-to-divide-ytics-to-a-certain-number-in-matplotlib)

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
```

Then, I would like to delete the decimals, so I use this line of code:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
```

However, I can't get both. My y-axis is divided by 1000 *or* without decimals, but not both formats.

Any idea?
In advance, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of retrospectively modifying the labels, you should change directly the formatter function:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr  


def numfmt(x, pos):
    s = f'{x/1000:,.0f}' #<----
    return s

yfmt = tkr.FuncFormatter(numfmt)
 
#sample data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"cat": list("ABCDE"), "xaxis": [1, 3, 4, 5, 9], "yaxis": [1236, 3213, 2123, 6243, 1432]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.xaxis, df.yaxis)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thks a lot!

Comment: I have to thank you for making me aware of the FuncFormatter class. Very handy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

How about below?

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)

ax.set_yticklabels(['{x:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks().tolist()])
```

Comment: Thks a lot. In my case, the previous response was more helpful because it used the function, but yours is helpful too. Thks.